# Do not trigger .keyup on context menus of textareas

Tags: jquery, keypress, keyboard-events

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$('#textbox').keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) { alert( 'You escaped!' ); }
});
```

Using the keyboard if I open the context menu to correct a word and then decide not to correct it and press "Esc" this textbox's `.keyup` is triggered.

[image: Context Menu]

http://jsfiddle.net/jesin/mr6ty820/

**How can I ensure the code inside `(e.keyCode == 27)` works only if escape is pressed for the textarea and not the context menu?**

Gmail's "Compose" box also closes on "Esc" but it doesn't exit if I press "Esc" for a context menu.

Comment: What plugin are you using for the context menu?

Comment: @IrvinDominin Nothing, spell check appears on Firefox if you have a "dictionary" installed. It also appears on IE11.

Answer (score 1):

You could listen for the right mouse button and set a variable when the context menu was active so that it did not also trigger on the ESC of your text field.

```
var contextMenu = false;

$('#textbox').bind('mousedown keyup', function (e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 27 && !contextMenu) {
        alert('You escaped!');
    }

    if (e.button == 2) {
        contextMenu = true;
    } else {
        contextMenu = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a great, nor guaranteed cross-browser, solution but might get you closer.  It works in latest Chrome, test for yourself in other browsers.  [See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lap3fs1q/)

```
var contextOpen = false;

$(document).on('contextmenu', function (e) {
    contextOpen = !contextOpen;
   console.log(e); 
});

$('#textbox').keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27 && !contextOpen) { alert( 'You escaped!' ); }
});

$('#textbox').on('keydown click focus', function () {
   contextOpen = false; 
});
```

This code basically keeps track of the opening of the context menu if the browser triggers a '[contextmenu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.oncontextmenu)' event which will prevent the Esc from running.  The difficulty is in tracking the 'close' event of the context menu as this is not available.  You have to work around this, so I've opted for resetting contextOpen when the #textbox receives either focus, a keydown, or click - as this will typically imply a reset.